# how to list downloaded apt packages without dependecies

Tags: linux, bash, apt

I'm trying to get the names of downloaded packages without dependencies..
I don't want to get **all** the files in */var/cache/apt/archives* .. I only want to get the **primary packages** without dependencies
I don't want to list files in /usr/share/applications either..

Comment: Either `apt-get download pkgname` or `aptitude download pkgname` should work, depending on the version of your distribution (which you don't specify).

Comment: Sorry but I want to get the names of all downloaded applications not download a certain package

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `/var/log/apt/history.log`

When you issue `apt-get install`, it records the command line as `Commandline:` record, and real packages installed as `Install:`

Comment: Well..this doesn't provide a list contains only packages without any additions.. but I can extract the names by using `substring` between the first two `:` after 'install'...Great job man :)